# Pandas aggregate with function with multiple parameters

Tags: pandas, group-by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('aabb'), 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [4, 2, 1, 3]})

def agg_func(x, y):
    return sum(x) > sum(y)
```

I need smth like that

```
df.groupby('a').agg({('b', 'c'): agg_func})
```

And expect

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the logic and provide the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I would simple aggregate the columns, and then perform the comparison:

```
g = df.groupby('a').sum()
out = g['b']>g['c']
```

With your function (probably less efficient):

```
out = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda g: agg_func(g['b'], g['c']))
```

output:

```
a    False
b     True
dtype: bool
```